# Facebook Dialog Feed - Hide share via link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using FB UI for sharing using feed method.

The page is sharing correctly.

Can anyone tell how to hide the share via "Facebook Application Name" link.

I'm using following code.

```
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: '<?php the_title(); ?>',
link: '<?php echo $urlofpage; ?>',
picture: '',
caption: '<?php echo bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>',
description: '',
message: ''
},
function(response) {
if (response && !response.error_code) {
if ( response && response.post_id ){
$.ajax({'url' :'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=<?php echo $urlofpage; ?>','success':function(data){
get_like_count(data.shares);

}});

}

}
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t hide that text, and it´s very important anyway. People should know if something got posted via an App and not by the user directly.